# Why is this function returning an empty vector?

Tags: c++

In the code below I am trying to return an array containing the longest strings of the `inputArray`. However, when I use it the array outputted is empty.

```
vector<string> solution(vector<string> inputArray) {
    int highestSize, add;
    vector<string> newArray{};

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); ++i) {
        highestSize = max(int(inputArray[i].length()), highestSize);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); ++i) {
        if (inputArray[i].length() == highestSize) {
            newArray[add] = inputArray[i];
            ++add;
        }
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: 1. You haven't initialized `highestSize, add` to `0`. 2. you haven't allocated space in `newArray` to use operator[]. You should use `push_back` instead.

Comment: A side note: passing `inputArray` by `const&` will be more efficient.

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry I meant it returned an empty vector

Comment: I recommend to [edit]  your question; to clarify and to get closer to [ask] and to [mre].

Comment: @wohlstad Thanks, your push_back suggestion worked! I'm still learning so didn't know of this function until now.

Comment: Note, you may find it confusing to use the word "array" in naming vectors.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't waste your time competing on judging sites before learning the language.

Comment: ... or after, for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are several issues in your code:**

1. `highestSize` and `add` are not initialized. In C++ variables are **not** default initialized to `0` as you might have expected.
2. `newArray` is default constructed to have 0 elements. In this case you cannot use [**`operator[]`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) the way you did. [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) can access only elements that were allocated. You can use [**`push_back`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to add to the vector. If your code was changed so that you knew in advance how many entries you will need in `newArray`, you could also [**`resize`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the `vector` and then use `operator[]` to access the elements. There are some more options like resereving capacity and using push_back, you can see more info [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).
3. It's better to pass  `inputArray` by `const&` to avoid an unneeded copy.

**A fixed version:**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> solution(std::vector<std::string> const & inputArray) {
    int highestSize{ 0 };
    std::vector<std::string> newArray{};
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); ++i)
    {
        highestSize = std::max(int(inputArray[i].length()), highestSize);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (inputArray[i].length() == highestSize)
        {
            newArray.push_back(inputArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

A side note: it's better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).